# Firebase function onCall, response: Warning, FIREBASE_CONFIG environment variable is missing. Initializing firebase-admin will fail

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I try to call my test function from local project.

But all time when i call, i take 401 error. I don't know what trouble here, in front end i have init app with api key, in firebase function i have `admin.credential.applicationDefault()`;
I tried to pass `admin.credential.cer(apiConfig)`, but this don't help to.

I also have Environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`, with path to my config.

**Dependencies**

```
    "firebase-admin": "~7.0.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.2.0",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.1.6",
```

**My function**

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault(),
    databaseURL: "https://plan-list.firebaseio.com"
});

exports.createInviteUser = functions.https.onCall( (data, context)=> {

  return data;

});
```

**Front-end function request**

```
 createInviteUser(email: string) {
        let inviteFunction = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('createInviteUser');

        inviteFunction(email)
            .then((result) => {
            // Read result of the Cloud Function.
           console.log(result);
        })
            .catch(err=>{
                console.log(err)
            });
    }
```

Also, how i see i have all required headers

[image]
**Here logs from console**

```
12:54:58.063 PM
createInviteUser
Warning, FIREBASE_CONFIG environment variable is missing. Initializing firebase-admin will fail
12:55:36.257 PM
createInviteUser
Function execution started
12:55:36.257 PM
createInviteUser
 Billing account not configured. External network is not accessible and quotas are severely limited. Configure billing account to remove these restrictions
12:55:36.271 PM
createInviteUser
Function execution took 15 ms, finished with status code: 204
12:55:36.573 PM
createInviteUser
Function execution started
12:55:36.573 PM
createInviteUser
Billing account not configured. External network is not accessible and quotas are severely limited. Configure billing account to remove these restrictions
12:55:36.951 PM
createInviteUser
Function execution took 379 ms, finished with status code: 401
```

Comment: Are you using Node version 10?  If so, see [this open issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/433).  You will need to downgrade to Node v8.

Comment: @BobSnyder ohhh goood, two days its blow my mind, thank you very much !

Comment: In the future, if you have a bug report for the Firebase CLI, please post to the project GitHub rather than Stack Overflow, or file a bug request with Firebase support.  Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This error occurs when functions are deployed with Node v10. It is caused by a [bug in firebase-functions](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/433).  There is a fix but it is not yet released.  Until it is, downgrade to Node v8 by changing your `package.json` file:

```
  "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  }
```