# Google cloud function: Warning, FIREBASE_CONFIG and GCLOUD_PROJECT environment variables are missing. Initializing firebase-admin will fail

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a google cloud function that will send me an email when a document is added to the Cloud firestore.

- Runtime envirment is: Nodejs 14

The function does work but in the logs I get a warning "Warning, FIREBASE_CONFIG and GCLOUD_PROJECT environment variables are missing. Initializing firebase-admin will fail" I don't really understand this warning.

Do you know of any solution? I don't want to see this warning. What do I have to do(solution).

I saw some people used nodejs 8 and it worked but I don't want to use nodejs 8.

I am very new to the cloud stuff. I am talking weeks. Please don't make you answer complicated.

here is the code:

```
"use strict";

const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

const FireStoreParser = require ("firestore-parser");

const { google } = require("googleapis");

admin.initializeApp();

exports.sendMail = functions.handler.firestore.document.onCreate(async(change,context) => {
  
  const OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2;
  const clientID = "you-dont-need-this";
  const clientSecret = "you-dont-need-this";
  const refreshToken = "you-dont-need-this"
  
  const oauth2Client = new OAuth2(
    clientID, //client Id
    clientSecret, // Client Secret
    "https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground" // Redirect URL
  );

  oauth2Client.setCredentials({
    refresh_token: refreshToken
  });
  
  const accessToken = await oauth2Client.getAccessToken()
    
  const smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: "gmail",
    auth: {
      type: "OAuth2",
      user: "you-dont-need-this",
      clientId: clientID,
      clientSecret: clientSecret,
      refreshToken: refreshToken,
      accessToken: accessToken
    }
  });
  
  const _fieldsProtoInJSON = FireStoreParser(change._fieldsProto);
  const textToMail = JSON.stringify(_fieldsProtoInJSON);
  
  var attachment = [
    {   // binary buffer as an attachment
        filename: 'dataContainer.json',
        content: textToMail
    }
  ];
  
  const mailOptions = {
    from: `<you-dont-need-this>`,
    to: 'you-dont-need-this,
    subject: `New message container ${_fieldsProtoInJSON.ContainerNumber} from ${_fieldsProtoInJSON.Tag}`,
    text: `See attachment for data.`,
    attachments: attachment
  };
  

  smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
      smtpTransport.close();
    }
    return "mail sent";
  });
});
```

this is the package.json

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "14"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^8.12.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.6.2",
    "firestore-parser": "0.9.0",
    "@google-cloud/storage": "^5.1.1",
    "googleapis": "^51.0.0",
    "nodemailer": "^6.4.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^5.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.0.1"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: Have you searched? Here's [one result](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-nodejs/issues/48)

Comment: yes I saw that they say set variable GCLOUD_PROJECT = project.id.  I don't know where to do this. I am not using any SDK's  I am doing this in side google cloud platform. Do you know where to put that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firebase function onCall, response: Warning, FIREBASE\_CONFIG environment variable is missing. Initializing firebase-admin will fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56097912/firebase-function-oncall-response-warning-firebase-config-environment-variabl)

Comment: I saw that one too. I am on node 14. Is the bug still there then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the issue by deploying the function using firebase cli. That way the variables are populated automatically.

check this link for an example: [Firebase CLI reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli)